My terminal isn't showing me the dirname in Python, I write the dir name but it doesn't return anything
import os 

father_dir = input("Type your directory: ")

try: 
    def return_dir_father(dir):
        return os.path.dirname(dir)

    res = return_dir_father(father_dir)
    print(res)
except TypeError:
    print("Erro")

I'm expecting it to show me the parent directory

What are you passing as an input? This works when I run it.

Though this is not the problem, the function definition should be outside of the try-block, preferably before the definition of father_dir.

For what it's worth, passing a path with a trailing slash like C:/one/two/ will return C:/one/two, while passing a path without a trailing slash, like C:/one/two will return C:/one

The question is not very clear and documented, you can look at the documentation of os.path.dirname here.
Maybe you didn't understand the function well: os.path.dirname() method in Python is used to get the directory name from the specified path.
Examples
Type your directory: C:/Users 
C:/

But
Type your directory: C:/Users/
C:/Users

I guess you where talking about these corner cases. Else, your code is working and if it's not on your computer edit your post and add more informations.

the actual documentation of os.path.dirname is here. geeksforgeeks is not related to the python software foundation

Your code looks correct. The result depends on what you are inputting. If you input a file name (e.g. file.txt) then it will return an empty string; however, if you input something like /home/User/Documents it will return /home/User.
